# How does DateTime.Now works?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I found some code looking like this one:

```
var obj = new SomeClass();
obj.FirstProperty = Magic.GetFirstProperty();
//...
obj.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
obj.ModificationDate = obj.CreateDate;
```

There were plenty of properties so I decided to refactor that code and use object initializer.

```
var obj = new SomeClass
{
    FirstProperty = Magic.GetFirstProperty();
    //...
    CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow
};
```

Rewriting property from one to another in object initialization block is impossible (as far as I know) and doing it out of block looks bad (in my opinion).

I decide to make a test and for 10 000 000 iterations I got from 600 to 1200 different pairs. This is code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var obj = new SomeClass
            {
                First = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Second = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            if (obj.First != obj.Second)
                Console.WriteLine(j++ + "  :  " + GetDateInfo(obj.First) + "  " + GetDateInfo(obj.Second));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of work");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string GetDateInfo(DateTime dateTime) =>
        $"{dateTime.Hour} : {dateTime.Minute} : {dateTime.Second} : {dateTime.Millisecond} -  {dateTime.Ticks}";
}

internal class SomeClass
{
    public DateTime First { get; set; }
    public DateTime Second { get; set; }
}
```

And here we have some results:

[image: Screenshot with results]

As you can see, some records like highlithed one, have only difference in procesor ticks.

At the same time, *javascript* was returning always equal values, apart from memory leaks in Google Chrome. Here is code:

```
var d,d2,n,n2;
for(var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    d = new Date();
    n = d.getTime();
    d2 = new Date();
    n2 = d.getTime();

    if(n===n2) 
        console.log("equal"); 
    else 
        console.log("not equal");  
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve that issue in .NET in proper way and how does DateTime.Now actually works? I'm pretty curious what is going on behind the scenes. **I was expecting that both values in one iterations/object intialization will be equal.**

Comment: You have a loop that needs some time to execute. Why do you expect that `DateTime.Now`/`UtcNow` will always return the same time? If you run the loop one week you still expect that you get the `DateTime` from last week? As to the "how does datetime works", read always the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: There is a severe typo in your code. It should be "n2 = **d2**.getTime();"

Comment: @TimSchmelter please read the OP's code again. He doesn't expect two different objects `DateTime` values to be the same, he expects two different properties of one same object to get same Date value

Comment: OP, .getTime() returns 13 digits, whereas .Ticks returns 18. That's a whole 5 digits of precision more. The difference you've highlighted is in the last 4 digits. Think about it.

Comment: @er-han His JavaScript test seems to contradict that.

Comment: @john I think his JS code doesn't contradict. He still gets two different variables in the same iterate

Comment: @marsze, you're absolutely right. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

> Do you have any idea how to solve that issue in .NET in proper way...

Solution is simple, just call DateTime.UtcNow once...

```
var dtNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
var obj = new SomeClass
{
    FirstProperty = Magic.GetFirstProperty();
    //...
    CreateDate = dtNow,
    ModificationDate = dtNow
};
```

In the case of a loop, if you want all the values to be exactly the same, then you should assign `dtNow` *before* the loop begins. i.e. only assign it once.

---

> ...how does DateTime.Now actually works?

In short, it gets the current value at the point that you call `DateTime.UtcNow`.

In long, you should check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx) and do further research if you are really interested.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. But i really wonder why OP expect that he gets old DateTime values if he runs a loop for some time

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I agree, that is a wonder... it would seem pretty obvious as to why a loop over time would results in different times

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm guessing OP expects the `UtcNow` call to only be done once, not realising that the object initialiser code is just syntactic sugar around several sequential calls. So the question isn't really about how DateTime.UtcNow works, it's about C# syntax.

Comment: @DavidG: something like that, but i still dont get it why someone expects that a statement inside of loop could be done only once, as if it was done outside. Maybe the fact that `Now` is a property confused him, but the name `Now` is quite meaningful ;)

Comment: I was expecting that both values in one iterations/object intialization will be equal. DateTime.Now called twice, one by one will give same result.

Comment: @Bear: I think the main confusion here is that you (incorrectly) think that `DateTime.Now` is a value. It is in fact a property that essentially acts like a function. By this, I mean that it performs some function to retrieve the current datetime each and every time the property to accessed. Although in your example the property is called twice *very* close together. it is not the exact same call, and therefore happens at 2 different points in time (even though they are relatively close). I hope that help clear things up?

Answer (score 3):

Js `Date.now()` method has millisecond resolution. If you need higher resolution, use `Performance.now()`. [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Officially, C# `DateTime` uses 100 ns ticks. But it is hard to achieve this resolution under practical circumstances. [High-Precision Code Timing in .NET](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021111.asp)

This means that if more than one tick passes between two calls to `DateTime.Now`, the created `DateTime` objects will have different values.

For your usecase, the simplest way to get the exact same timestamp would be to call `DateTime.Now` only once and assign this value.

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var obj = new SomeClass
   {
       FirstProperty = Magic.GetFirstProperty();
       (...)
       CreateDate = now,
       ModificationDate = now 
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now (and UtcNow) use internal windows functions to return the current time. It will return the current time everytime you call it, so there will be tiny differences between calls of course.

Solutions:

- Assign the current time to a variable and use that variable to init the obj properties.
- If that is your own class, create a proper constructor that inits the properties automatically.

This is different from JavaScript, where the current time is set once you create the Date object. Calling any of its functions will return the time of the creation of the object.